# JPA: Using @Embeddable and @EmbeddedId with interfaces

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, interface

I want to implement the following two interfaces and map them to a database using JPA and Hibernate.

```
public interface IThing {
    public IKey getId();
    public void setId(IKey id);
}

public interface IKey {
    public String getS();
    public void setS(String s);
    public Boolean getB();
    public void setB(Boolean b);
}
```

So a `Key` should be an object with two fields. Their names and types don't matter. The important thing is that `Key` is a compound key for `Thing`.

Simple (or whatever is considered simple for Java code) implementations:

```
@Entity
public class Thing implements IThing, java.io.Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private IKey id;

    public IKey getId() {
       return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(IKey id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class Key implements IKey, java.io.Serializable {
    private String s;
    private Boolean b;

    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }
    public void setS(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public Boolean getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(Boolean b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Now, you don't even have to use them, their mere presence and the creation of an EntityManager seem to be enough to trigger this:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: example] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at example.Main.main(Main.java:7)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: example.IKey has no persistent id property: example.Thing.id
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindComponent(AnnotationBinder.java:2301)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2021)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:796)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:4035)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3989)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1398)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1375)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1519)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1100)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:366)
    ... 10 more
```

While I can use this (note how it is not implementing `IThing` and ignoring the `IKey` interface) without error:

```
@Entity
public class Thing2 implements java.io.Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private Key id;

    public Key getId() {
       return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(Key id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I did not find any way to make the version using interfaces work. Is it possible to implement the two interfaces and make the resulting implementation classes into proper JPA `@Entity` and `@EmbeddedId`?

(This might be related to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821439/embeddable-and-embeddedid-consists-only-of-complex-classes), at least the error is similar.)

Comment: Don't think Hibernate supports interfaces as such, you have to specify "targetEntity" on annotations to specify the implementation being used, so perhaps you ought to do that. The implementation I use (DataNucleus) does support interfaces as a JPA vendor extension, allowing me to model classes and interfaces as I want, but its not in the JPA spec

Comment: @NeilStockton I tried `@EmbeddedId(targetEntity = Key.class) private IKey id;` but I get an `error: cannot find symbol`. So do you think I have to use a different approach entirely? Maybe IdClass? (I have to keep the interfaces and I can't use non-JPA fearutes either)

Comment: An interface IS a non-JPA feature.

Comment: @NeilStockton So if someone tasks me with implementing the interfaces while using only JPA, what do I tell them? I'm not Bartleby the Scrivener. :-D

Comment: I've never needed to do this, but have you tried adding `@Embeddable` to the `IKey` interface as well?

Comment: @coladict I just tried, no luck. I'll try to use IdClass instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is possible.

Use interface for this purpose in my experience with reflection is impossible because first of all the `@Embeddable` is applied on target class and not on the interface an then in many case the mechanism of many framework with reflection need of a specific class for be able to instance the class.... for an interface of course will be impossible instance it because interface in Java is a special case of abstract class.

I hope that this can help you

Comment: Well, it would be best to know for sure ;-) Do you think I need to use IdClass instead?

Comment: yess the my persona advice is when use some framework that use reflection use concrete class

Comment: teh key point of my uncertainty is becouse I don't know as Hibernate implements the annotation processing but in my opinion is clear that use interface or abstract class with relfection isn't a good idea more over if use framework that use it and yon don't know how it works in detail. it sufficient that in some line of code the framework say yourClass.instance() and you get an exception

Comment: Very sorry I misreaded the your comment about IdClass. In my opinion the EmbeddedId was the best aproach ba you should use a concrete class and not interface or abstract class

Comment: Okay, but I fear I have to stick with the interfaces.

Comment: if you need to generalaize the your id class try to use concrete class and use this as base of you hierarchy. In this case you shouldn't incur in exception about the use of interface.